# What leads our reaction regarding a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I am wondering...

Regarding [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61123/need-help-with-a-very-coblex-modeling-for-me), our reaction is first, to ask about more precision, etc., then to close it (and for now maintain it closed despite the edit by the OP).

Regarding [this other one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/techniques-for-modeling-a-network-of-blood-vessels), let's say, we have a neutral reaction.

Objectively, I don't see why. For both :

- Question about a method or how to
- No real proof of an attempt to have done or tried anything
- Based on a simple internet image

Surely the second one needs much more technics (or addon or work...) than the first one. But is that the reason ?

My own reaction was for the first to think "... again more or less a 'simple' modeling task" and for the second one "... interesting, I am curious to see an answer for that".
But I really think, my reaction is very subjective and not so good indeed.

Finally, one can still be answered and not the other one... fair / unfair, justified / not justified ?

What is your opinion ?

Comment: 3 months later, 1st question has 9 UVs and 2 answers with 10/8 UVs. The 2nd question has 24 UVs and 2 answers with 23/16 UVs... That's why a community is amazing, what you (or me) think is bad or useless, someone else has something to say about it, and other people are interested in the details...

Comment: @Bithur  Very well put, Bithur. +1 comment. The COMMUNITY has spoken and has upvoted the questions. 'Nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the second ([Techniques for modeling a network of blood vessels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/61261/2217)) I think it should be closed. It does seam way too broad. I expect now that you have brought more attention to it is will get closed. (I would close it now, except that I want you to get more responses here first.)

The first question is definitely answerable, it just needed to be cleaned up a bit (see [my edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/61123/revisions)). I went ahead and reopened it.

In this case, I think it is more about who has seen the question(s) rather then some difference in quality.

Comment: I think both may stay open. But I still feel it subjective. A question like "how can I extrude?" can lead to model a "network of blood vessels"... so...

Comment: As originally written, the first question was a "can someone do this for me?" kind of question, hence the bad reaction. On the second one I'm waiting (hoping it stays open) to give a nice bounty.... But it is all subjective....

Comment: And as subjective as the question are the reactions to the answers. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/techniques-for-modeling-a-network-of-blood-vessels